# Перелом ли конструкции, или Те ли знаки я нарисовала?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, – мне
>   кажется: тот самый аккомпанемент.

Скобки не предлагать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хозяин - барин, какой смысл вкладываешь - такова и пунктуация. Возможен и Ваш, Галина, вариант, но тогда это будет не перелом конструкции. Sharon права, при переломе двучастная конструкция:

*Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, – мне кажется, тот самый аккомпанемент.*

А почему, если значение "*кажется мне:* *самый ТОТ аккомпанемент!*", не написать именно так:

*Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, – кажется мне, самый  тот  аккомпанемент.*

Можно акценты чуть переставить:

*Завтрак получился под Шопена: пасмурно и чуть накрапывает – самый  тот  аккомпанемент.*

*"Мне кажется"* отвлекает внимание на себя, его нужно или  убрать совсем, или переставить в конец предложения:

*Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, –  тот самый аккомпанемент, как мне кажется.*

Answer (score 1):

**Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, – мне кажется, тот самый аккомпанемент.**

Я бы считала, что это бессоюзная связь, обозначенная тире. Тогда вторая часть предложения – это комментарий по отношению к  первой.

Запятая закрывает придаточное.

Мне кажется – вводное предложение. *Буран, мне казалось, всё ещё свирепствовал* (П.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Comment: Шарончик, я думаю и я тут... Я ведь почему двоеточие нарисовала, - у меня *мне кажется* не вводное, а: *кажется мне: самый ТОТ аккомпанемент!* Самое то, сленговое.

Comment: Я знаки по интонации ставлю, и вот тире, а потом двоеточие в этом предложении прочитать сложно. А вот интонацию любую можно изобразить. Двоеточие - это всего лишь подчеркнутая пауза, влияющая на ударение. Важно не то, что "мне кажется" вводное, а то, что интонационно  нужно подчеркнуть и выделить. Вторую часть  можно перестроить разными способами, меняя порядок слов, тогда и ударение изменится. Например: Завтрак получился под Шопена, когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, –  самый тот аккомпанемент, (как) мне кажется.

Comment: Если рассматривать только знаки препинания, то тире и двоеточие - это сильные знаки, которые конкурируют между собой. Они разделят небольшое предложение на три части, а эта конструкция двухчастная, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что *когда пасмурно...* — это вы объясняете свою ассоциацию с Шопеном?

Если да, то:

1. Стоит поставить между первой и второй частью тире ([Лопатин, § 79 (знаки препинания при уточняющих, пояснительных и присоединительных членах предложения)](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123)):

   > Завтрак получился под Шопена — когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, мне кажется — тот самый аккомпанемент.

   Или вообще можно вынести пояснение в отдельное предложение:

   > Завтрак получился под Шопена. Когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, мне кажется — тот самый аккомпанемент.
2. Также меня смущает последнее тире и обрубок подчинённого предложения после него. Думаю, стоит дополнить его до «кажется, что это...»:

   > Завтрак получился под Шопена — когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, мне кажется, что это тот самый аккомпанемент.
   >
   > Завтрак получился под Шопена. Когда пасмурно и чуть накрапывает, мне кажется, что это тот самый аккомпанемент.