# С запятой или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Посмотрим, что уже написано **(,)** и как это можно будет дополнить.

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Посмотрим, что уже написано  и как это можно будет дополнить*.

Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя однородными придаточными, запятой нет.

Comment: Люсенька! https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449848/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%A2%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0/449867?noredirect=1#comment460533_449867